# Install4J Auto update Version Detection

Tags: install4j

We have created installer for our eclipse RCP Application using install4j. We have single installer with Version 'X'. We have mutliple server profiles to connect to with version 'X'.
We are taking below inputs from user during installation -

1. Installation Directory - <Installation_Path/AppName_ServerProfile_X
2. Server Profile to connect to - Server_Profile_X

However we are facing an issue during auto update mechanism -
Auto update fails to locate installation directory with server profile and again prompts for an input for installation directory and server profile to connect to during an auto update.

As per my understanding, this is because Application ID doesn't contain any information related to Server Profile.
How can we ensure that our server profile name is tagged with 'Application ID' somehow so that, it can detect installation directory with server profile automatically?

Below is snippet for update options -

[image]

Comment: The application ID should be a fixed string and not contain a release if you want and update installer to find the previous installation directory. I'm not sure about your "server profiles", do you mean that you have multiple installations on the same machine and want to update all of them? Then the update installer will not be able to find a unique installation. You would then have to launch the update programmatically in some way from the update downloader.  The update downloader is just a template and compose of screens and actions and can be customized in any way you like.

Comment: Hi Igor, What I mean for -                                                                                             
I'm not sure about your "server profiles", do you mean that you have multiple installations on the same machine and want to update all of them?                                                    I wish to have multiple installation on same machine for different server profiles for example - one for development server profile, one for production server profile, one for testing server profile. However When i launch any one of the launcher only specific server must be updated.

Comment: Also I want to place my updates.xml path relative to serverURL we are getting from user. Is there any way to update this path during installation. For Example, if uer gives serverURL as https://XX.XX.XX.XX:10540 then updates.xml auto update url must be https://XX.XX.XX.XX:10540/rcp-client/updates.xml. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but you must tell the installation what the URL is, so it can check it. Locate the "Check for update" action in your downloader, there you can see that the URL is taken from `Update descriptor URL ${installer:updatesUrl?:${compiler:sys.updatesUrl}}´ by default, meaning first from the installer variable `updatesUrl` and if that is not defined them the compiler variable `updatesUrl` which contains the value you entered on "Installer->Auto-Opdate Options". So you can define the installer variable `updatesUrl` (as a response file variable) in the installer.